# MSVS2013 - Neon intrinsics VTBL2: different result in debug mode vs release mode. How can I fix this?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, simd, neon, release-mode

I've cobbled together a neon equivalent to the SSE2 intrinsic _mm_shuffle_epi8.

The code I currently have for this purpose is:

```
        static __forceinline __n128 shuffle8(
            const __n128& a,
            __n128 b) throw()
        {
            __n64x2 in =
            {
                a.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.low64,
                a.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.high64
            };
            b.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.low64 = vtbl2_u8(in, b.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.low64);
            b.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.high64 = vtbl2_u8(in, b.DUMMYNEONSTRUCT.high64);
            return b;
        }
```

Now, I'm not necessarily set on this being the final form of things; but that's not the question yet.  I've been testing my code and have found that what I've given works exactly as I intend it to when building/running in debug mode, but NOT when building/running in release mode.  By way of example:

```
#define simd_shuffle8(a, b) shuffle8(a, b)

...

simd test = keyschedule[1];
test = simd_shuffle8(test, test);
```

keyschedule[1] has an initial value of

```
{0x858efc16, 0x8801f2e2, 0x1f0fb923, 0x11ecb78e}
```

In debug mode, test ends with a value of

```
{0x00000000, 0x00fc0000, 0x00110000, 0x00000000}
```

which is as it should be.  In release mode, test ends with a value of

```
{0x16161616, 0x16001616, 0x16161616, 0x16001616}
```

which is not as it should be.  What is likely to be causing this issue/how might I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As it so happens, after testing a bit I found that assigning the low64 and high64 DUMMYNEONSTRUCT values separately seems to be the part that causes problems --interestingly, the output changes depending on the order in which I assign them.  Looks like a bug in MSVS so far as I can tell.  Anyway, to anyone who's interested, I got around this by returning a vcombine.  That produced the correct output.